# Are "Featured" and "Bounties" different things?

Tags: support, design, bounty

Is are a reason why a question with a bounty on it is referred to as "Featured" on the main page, but seemingly called "Bounties" everywhere else? With both uses of the word, the button it is in is also styled differently (Not by a lot, but visibly different). I always thought it was the same, but maybe there are other criteria to "Featured" I've been unaware of? IF so, what are these criteria?

When looking at the tabs of a specific tag, the third tab is "bounties", with the number of active bounties displayed on the right side of the text

[image: Bounties, cirkled]

However, when you're on the home page it is called "Featured", with the number of active bounties displayed on the left side of the text

[image]

But there is more. If you scroll all the way to the bottom of the "Featured" page and click "*Looking for more featured questions? Browse the complete list.*" it will be renamed back to "Bounties" with the amount of bounties on the right side of the text.

[image]

The styling between for the counter showing the amount of bounties is also different between "Bounties" and "Featured"

- Background colour

  - "Bounties" has background colour #07C
  - "Featured" has background colour #0077dd
- Font size

  - "Bounties" is font size 11px
  - "Featured" is font size 10px
- Border radius

  - "Bounties" has no border-radius
  - "Featured" has a 2px border-radius

The blue box showing the amount of bounties next to the "Featured" text doesn't align with the text nicely either.

Looking at the [tag info](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/featured-questions/info) for [featured-questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured-questions) also seems to indicate that "Featured" and "Bounties" are the same thing, just named inconsistently.

> Questions and discussion about Meta questions that are tagged with [featured]. For questions about the Featured Questions tab of the questions page, use [bounties] instead.

Observed in Google Chrome Version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)

*Tagging it as a support question for now, as I'm not sure if this is intended, and I'm just unaware of it, or if it's an actual oversight*

Comment: A question with a bounty is listed as "featured". One is consequence of the other, but they are different things. That one button says "bounties" and the other "featured" is inconsistent, but not an absolute disaster. Bounties would mean "active bounties" in this context.

Comment: Could you expand on what makes "featured" different? Is it tied to other stats like views, popularity of the tag or something similar? I can't seem to find any resources that explain what "Featured" exactly means then, if not just "has a bounty". Maybe i've just overlooked/not found the page explaining this though. @yivi

Comment: It's not tied to any other thing. If a question has an active bounty, it's featured. Once the bounty is no longer active, the question ceases to be featured.

Comment: I feel like this changed very recently. Didn't the Bounties tab used to be called Featured everywhere? I swear that's how it was last week.

Comment: @MasonSchmidgall Yeah I feel like that is the case aswel.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330326/custom-filters-release-announcement

Comment: @JL2210 Thanks for linking that, and posting the link to this Q over there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Bounty is an *action*; featured is a *status*.

When you set a bounty on a question, that causes the question to be featured, so it shows up on the “featured” tab.

Notably, this “featured” status is the only thing you’re paying for with a bounty. You aren’t guaranteed to get an answer. You still pay the reputation price of the bounty even if the question never gets an acceptable answer (or any answer). What you got was it forced into the spotlight for the bounty period, a process called “featured”.

That said, there is some inconsistency in the UI, as cited in the question. That should be fixed. In ye olden days, all the tabs/views said “featured”, because that was the status of those questions. We should return to that.

Comment: Calling them "featured" is misleading to someone who doesn't understand what the bounty system is. If I don't know any user can pay reputation to put a question in "featured," then I might be inclined to think it's some kind of system of identifying useful or interesting questions. We should abandon it for something more clear, not return to it. "Bounties" is an example of a more clear option, though it does have the very minor downside of not being an adjective like the other tabs.

Comment: why not "bountied"? or "rewarded"/"rewardable"

Comment: Featured bounties

Comment: Although anything can be verbified, "bounty" itself is *not* a verb.

Comment: From the asker's perspective, bounty makes it featured indeed. From the answerer's perspective though, what's interesting about the question is that you can earn the bounty (and not that someone wants you to see it, per se). Since the UI we're looking at is (IMO) used primarily to look for questions to answer, it might be useful to prefer the answerer's point of view.

Comment: Actually, _offering a bounty_ is the action; _bounty_ is a noun that in the context of list of questions should be understood as _questions with a bounty_.  _Featured_ could be understood as @jpmc26 said, since that is the meaning most of the sites gives to that word.

Answer (score 18):

They are the same thing: `bounties == featured`.

You are correct; this is a naming inconsistency. All questions that have bounties are "featured" so they get more attention.

Don't confuse "Featured" on Main with "Featured" on Meta. The latter has to do with questions on Meta tagged with [featured](/questions/tagged/featured), which is a special tag on Meta that can be added to questions by Stack Overflow employees or moderators.

Comment: I think the last paragraph is yet another reason for using "Bounties" or similar everywhere. As jpmc26 suggests, "Featured" sounds like some person or algorithm picked those ones out, or that someone paid (actual money I mean) for it, and corresponds more to its meaning in Meta. I understand the difference Cody makes, but I don't think it really adds any value.

Comment: I have a slight itch about the equality stated here. Bountied is Featured but Featured is not necessary Bountied :)